# Npm upgrading to latest with Homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

I'm looking for an official procedure to update the version of the npm included in node (installed via homebrew).

**cli configs**

```
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v11.4.0 darwin x64"
userconfig /Users/antoniomavaro/.npmrc
prefix = "/Users/antoniomavaro/.npm-packages"
node bin location = /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.4.0/bin/node
cwd = /Users/antoniomavaro
HOME = /Users/antoniomavaro
```

Installing via ***npm install npm @latest -g I install npm*** as a module in its own right but it does not updates the bundled version installed with homebrew.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Homebrew, it should work out of the box. Is it what I've done:

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm

$ npm --version
6.4.1

$ npm install -g npm
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.5.0
added 2 packages from 1 contributor and updated 14 packages in 8.139s

$ npm --version
6.5.0
```

Comment: write permission denied, is it safe to run this with sudo? I have installed npm with homebrew and it works fine, but I want to update npm to its latest version. Can I do `sudo npm install -g npm`?